# Install php72 on MacOS using brew

Tags: php, homebrew, php-7.2, php-7.3

I'm trying to install php72 using brew.

Actually when I do `brew install php72` it's downloading "https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/php-7.3.0.mojave.bottle.tar.gz".

So when I check php version it's showing me PHP 7.3.0 (cli).

How can I install exactly php72 and not php73 ?

Comment: have you run the command `brew unlink php73` ?

Comment: Yes and it don't find it. To unlink it I have to run `brew unlink php72`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution.

Instead of installing php72 you must specify version like this php@7.2.

```
brew unlink [your actual php version linked]
brew install php@7.2
brew link php@7.2
```

Answer (score 3):

> Installing PHP 7.2 on Mac using Homebrew
>
> Check version

```
  php -v
```

> check brew is up to date

```
  brew update

  brew upgrade
```

> Unlink php version which is installed in the system

```
  brew unlink php71
```

> Now final step to download**

```
  brew install php72

  export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
brew upgrade
brew unlink php71
brew install php72
```

then in your ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/php\@7.2/7.2.26/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: awesome, because i cannot do unlink, i just do brew install, then put that export text in ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

```
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew unlink php71
brew install php72 --with-argon2 
brew install php72-xdebug
```

For more info follow url https://murze.be/how-to-upgrade-from-php-71-to-72-on-macos-using-homebrew

Answer (score 0):

Note older version's of Mac OS are not supported, I'm trying with docker which also doesn't support older versions of Mac OS completely (no desktop version).  Trying with just docker machine as follows;

```
base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0 &&
  curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/usr/local/bin/docker-machine &&
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```